# SuiteScript or Workflow to turn on/off auto-generated numbers

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a division that imports invoices into our NetSuite environment using the CSV import function. Works quite well, however, our other divisions within NetSuite require Auto Generated Numbering to be turned on WITHOUT override capability. This means, every time the csv import is ready, I as the admin, must turn on 'allow override' and then allow them to import. Then turn off the override when they communicate they are finished. The purpose of the override is to keep the invoice sequence the same as the authoring invoice. We can then track the invoices in each system. The question is, has anyone every attempted to create a script or workflow to allow the user to turn this function on/off for importing? Is this even feasible?

Let me know your thoughts!

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do that and in my experience (21 years of Netsuite) this sort of effort generally doesn't scale.

If the document number you are trying to import matches another transaction's document number then what tends to work is to create a custom transaction body field of type list/record -> transaction and populate that with the cross reference in your import.

If you are just trying to maintain a reference to another system's invoice numbers then create a custom transaction body field of type text (or integer) and make it globally searchable (that's a checkbox on field setup). Import your external reference to that and edit that division's forms to show it under the Netsuite generated document number. Users can search transactions by the external reference. It can be shown on pdfs etc etc.